# I want to unnest multiple values as columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

```
select
  case
    when subq.status = 1
        then unnest(
                        string_to_array('batman,v,superman', ',')
                )
    else null
  end as something
from (
    select 1 as status
) subq
```

This code unnests some values as rows. Is it even possible to unnest these as columns with custom column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access each element of an array by it's index, eg.:

```
select a[1] as first, a[2] as second, a[3] as third
from string_to_array('batman,v,superman', ',') a
```